# Sort and Re-apply Deltas of an Array

Tags: code-golf, array, sorting, integer

It seems that any [Simple](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/101057/inverse-deltas-of-an-array) [Modification](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/102139/reverse-deltas-of-an-array) of deltas using a consistent function can almost always be done some other [shorter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/101058/58375) [way](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/102163/58375), *Dennis*.
Thus, the only solution I can imagine to make this harder, is to introduce some sort of inconsistent function.

**Sorting.**

Your task is to take an array of integers, sort their deltas, and recompile that to give the new array of integers.

### EG.

For the input:

```
1  5 -3  2  9
```

Get the following Deltas:

```
  4 -8  5  7
```

Then, sort these Deltas, Yielding:

```
 -8  4  5  7
```

And reapply them, which gives:

```
1 -7 -3  2  9
```

### Input/Output

You will be given a list/array/table/tuple/stack/etc. of signed integers as input through any standard input method.

You must output the modified data once again in any acceptable form, following the above delta sorting method.

You will receive N inputs where `0 < N < 10` where each number falls within the range `-1000 < X < 1000`

### Test Cases

```
1 5 -3 2 9   -> 1 -7 -3 2 9
-5 -1 -6 5 8 -> -5 -10 -7 -3 8
-8 1 -7 1 1  -> -8 -16 -16 -8 1
8 -9 3 0 -2  -> 8 -9 -12 -14 -2
-5 -2 -5 5 0 -> -5 -10 -13 -10 0
-1 9 -1 -7 9 -> -1 -11 -17 -7 9
```

### Notes

- As stated in above, you will always receive at least 1 input, and no more than 9.
- The first and last number of your output, will **always** match that of the input.
- Only [Standard Input Output](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods?noredirect=1&lq=1) is accepted
- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) apply
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the lowest byte-count wins!
- Have fun!

Comment: IMO you should remove the second header (the one in the body of the post itself). It's kinda ugly and just takes up space, and it's a copy of the title (which is like 20 px above it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
IṢ;@Ḣ+\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@@/5cOcia4eHOxZpx/w/3P6oaY37///RhjoKpjoKusY6CkY6CpaxOgrRuiA@UFjXDCxlARaz0FEACZmDKUOQEFBE11JHAajRAMgygusEGgOigcgALAZUbwk10BxkAwA)

#### How it works

```
IṢ;@Ḣ+\  Main link. Argument: A (array)

I        Increments; compute the deltas.
 Ṣ       Sort them.
    Ḣ    Head; pop and yield the first element of A.
  ;@     Concatenate with swapped arguments.
     +\  Take the cumulative sum.
```

Answer (score 5):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 8 bytes

```
1)GdShYs
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@2@o6Z4SnBFZ/P9/tKGCgqmCrrGCgpGCgmUsAA)

```
1)   % Implicit input. Get its first entry
G    % Push input again
d    % Differences
S    % Sort
h    % Concatenate
Ys   % Cumulative sum. Implicit display
```

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica, 40 bytes

```
FoldList[Plus,#&@@#,Sort@Differences@#]&
```

Pure function taking a list of (anythings) as input and returning a list. `FoldList[Plus` starts with a number (in this case, `#&@@#`, the first element of the input) and repeatedly adds elements of the self-explanatory list `Sort@Differences@#`. This mimics the behavior of the built-in `Accumulate`, but the first number would need to be prepended to the list of differences by hand, which makes the byte-count higher (as far as I can tell).

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 9 bytes

-4 thanks to [Emigna](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/47066/emigna)

```
¬=s¥{vy+=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@39ojW3xoaXVZZXatv//R@sa6igoWOoogGhdcxA7FgA)

```
¬         # Get the head
 =        # Print
  s¥{     # Get sorted Deltas
     vy   # For each
       += # Add to the previous value and print
```

Comment: You could save 4 bytes with `¬=s¥{vy+=`

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell, 59 Bytes

```
import Data.List
f l@(a:b)=scanl1(+)$a:(sort$zipWith(-)b l)
```

Breakdown:

```
f l@(a:b) =           --we create a function f that takes as input a list l with head a and tail b
zipWith(-)b l        --we make a new list with the deltas
sort$                    --sort it
a:                          --prepend a to the list
scanl1(+)$          --create a new list starting with a and adding the deltas to it cumulatively
```

Comment: `scanl(+)a$sort...`

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, 92 bytes

```py
l=input();p=0;d=[]
r=l[0],
for e in l:d+=e-p,;p=e
for e in sorted(d[1:]):r+=r[-1]+e,
print r
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/),

## <strike>90 bytes</strike>

```
x=input()
print[sum(sorted(map(int.__sub__,x[1:],x[:-1]))[:i])+x[0]for i in range(len(x))]
```

## 84 bytes

Saved 6 bytes on using lambda. Thanks to ovs!

```python
lambda x:[sum(sorted(map(int.__sub__,x[1:],x[:-1]))[:i])+x[0]for i in range(len(x))]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#FYtBCsMgEAC/ssddqiWeSoW@ZLuIIbYIaoIm4O@tvczMZdLrPZLP6@ahW25XxrbXM2yY/YGxnHfn2rU6pzobK5NWGyFiG4VunRf57BUixALVl2/AFAp2IhlHnTckZG0UPBX8pR8zhcYP)

Breaking down the code,

```python
>>> x
[1, 5, -3, 2, 9]
>>> map(int.__sub__,x[1:],x[:-1]) #delta
[4, -8, 5, 7]
>>> sorted(map(int.__sub__,x[1:],x[:-1])) #sorted result
[-8, 4, 5, 7]
>>> [sorted(map(int.__sub__,x[1:],x[:-1]))[:i]for i in range(len(x))]
[[], [-8], [-8, 4], [-8, 4, 5], [-8, 4, 5, 7]]
>>> [sum(sorted(map(int.__sub__,x[1:],x[:-1]))[:i])+x[0]for i in range(len(x))]
[1, -7, -3, 2, 9]
```

Happy Coding!

Comment: i was trying to find a way to do it like that!

Comment: You can save some bytes by converting this into a function: `lambda x:[sum(sorted(map(int.__sub__,x[1:],x[:-1]))[:i])+x[0]for i in range(len(x))]`

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript (ES6), 68 bytes

```
([p,...a])=>[s=p,...a.map(e=>p-(p=e)).sort((a,b)=>b-a).map(e=>s-=e)]
```

In JavaScript it turns out to be golfier to compute the [Inverse Deltas of an Array](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/101057/inverse-deltas-of-an-array). These are then sorted in descending order and cumulatively subtracted from the first element.

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 7 bytes

```
∫:←¹OẊ-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//1HHaqtHbRMO7fR/uKtL9////9GGOqY6usY6RjqWsQA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 97 bytes

```python
p=input()
d=[p[i+1]-p[i] for i in range(len(p)-1)]
o=p[:1]
for n in sorted(d):o+=o[-1]+n,
print o
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#FcoxCkMhDADQ3VNkVIyDLR36wZOEDAVtCZQkWHt@2z@95W1vov5dMYXeyEly5fKH4WkTBERhPvQ14nto9FRq4mDN6agczqHn@Nhco8eeDsvNqFTOisGn6ALbmyresFzxgnf@AQ)

Comment: You can delete a space in the list comprehension for 96 bytes: `[p[i+1]-p[i]for i in range(len(p)-1)]`

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 93 bytes

```
(p,M=[p[0]])=>p.map((a,b)=>p[b+1]-a).sort((a,b)=>a-b).map((a,b)=>M=[...M,M[b]+a])[p.length-2]
```

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 11 bytes

```
.u+NYS.+QhQ
```

This just does the obvious thing described in the statement.

[Try It Online](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=.u%2BNYS.%2BQhQ&input=%5B1%2C+5%2C-3%2C+2%2C+9%5D&debug=0)

```
      .+Q    Take the deltas of the input
     S       sort it
.u           Cumulative reduce
  +NY        using addition
         hQ  starting with the first element of the input
```

Suggestions for further golfing welcome.

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 0.5](http://julialang.org/), 30 bytes

```julia
!x=[x[];x|>diff|>sort]|>cumsum
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/julia5#PY3BCoMwEETP9SvGWwsbUEuroTQ/EjzVBgI1SlTIIf@ebkIpLMzu253ZVIenDnp8hKgma0xU2@L3MarXMW/HnMziEWAdzrol3AjiSugIciRokWfG4l5WQ2EDIaO@SJsREyEJbGy46/5OjsnK1RTG9/IX2OcPl@pUB0SF1Vu3f1z1dlP6Ag)

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2 with numpy, <s>67</s> 56 bytes

```
from numpy import*
lambda l:cumsum(l[:1]+sorted(diff(l)))
```

Let numpy compute the deltas, sort them, prepend the first element, and let numpy compute the cumulative sums. Pretty cheap?

Comment: Save 3 bytes by changing the import to `from numpy import*` and `n.cumsum` to `cumsum` and `n.diff` to `diff`

Comment: Thanks. You can tell its been a while since I golfed python, forgetting all the standard tricks.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 89 bytes

```
for($a=$argv;n|$i=$a[++$x+1];)$d[]=$i-$a[$x];for(sort($d);$x-$y++;)echo$a[1]+=$d[$y-2],_;
```

Run like this:

```
php -nr 'for($a=$argv;n|$i=$a[++$x+1];)$d[]=$i-$a[$x];for(sort($d);$x-$y++;)echo$a[1]+=$d[$y-2],",";' 1  5 -3  2  9;echo
> 1_-7_-3_2_9_
```

## Explanation

```
for(
  $a=$argv;          # Set input to $a.
  n | $i=$a[++$x+1]; # Iterate over input.
)
  $d[] = $i-$a[$x];  # Add an item to array $d, with the difference between
                       the current and previous item.

for(
  sort($d);          # Sort the delta array.
  $x-$y++;           # Loop as many times as the previous loop.
)
  echo
    $a[1]+=$d[$y-2], # Print the first input item with the delta applied
                     # cumulatively. First iteration takes $d[-1], which
                     # is unset, so results in 0.
    _;               # Print underscore as separator.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pushy](https://github.com/FTcode/Pushy), 17 bytes

```
@ZL:&v+;Fg@Lt:K-#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Kygtzqj8/98hysdKrUzb2i3dwafEyltX@f///9FGOgqGOgq6QErXMBYA)

```
@ZL:&v+;F           \ Calculate cumulative sum
         g          \ Sort
          @Lt:K-#   \ Calculate and print deltas
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), 31 bytes

```perl6
{[\+] @_[0],|sort @_[1..*]Z-@_}
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/nexus/perl6#jVFrToNAEP6/p5iodaG4tIB92ZZyAE9gaRoCWyUWqGVpbZATeQsvVmcXqP4xETLZmflePIqcw2FohlOSnOA2zCIO83O59I0VeOtlf3X3kWd7IXvLNLurJ@atqzNSPcFzAXPYxinPNd1Mgt0DlAQg6YE3i9NdIVyENcrowo8M3YAOUKBIwMvPu0CZS2VTb7wZf9/xUPDoD1VvKr0xV1kjx/j6bHMayG8tWvRiaT7GuZCsXASCw02YFang@ylphHueF1tpKt9fqyP0RoSUa4jiCI4cnrmA40sgZN@aL5AQb6Cx4G@HC6I@B2YGJ7jKXqE0jDa4QsuyVpibRGi040RUr66QXwHf4i/5JU0zAf@Xk@pswQCYAzZM0IK5YAEbNQvCEMJ5iJSxxNTcbwhjwsY128JbwUiyhnUhRHCcgAMosBWuZmbZWPe4U/a2NB1Izo@95aizTzB8op5gJE9XtZaskVp9Aw)

### Expanded:

```perl6
{
  [\+]            # triangle produce values using &infix<+>
    @_[0],        # starting with the first argument
    |             # slip the following into this list
      sort        # sort the following

         # generate the list of deltas

         @_[1..*] # the arguments starting with the second one
         Z[-]     # zipped using &infix:<->
         @_       # the arguments
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Batch, 197 bytes

```
@set n=%1
@set s=
:l
@set/ad=5000+%2-%1
@set s=%s% %d%
@shift
@if not "%2"=="" goto l
@echo %n%
@for /f %%a in ('"(for %%b in (%s%)do @echo %%b)|sort"') do @set/an+=%%a-5000&call echo %%n%%
```

`sort` doesn't sort numerically, so I bias all the differences by 5000.

Answer (score 0):

### bash + sort, 102 bytes

```
echo $1
n=$1
shift
for e in $*
do
echo $((e-n))
n=$e
done|sort -n|while read e
do
echo $((n+=e))
done
```

### sh + sort + expr, 106 bytes

```
echo $1
n=$1
shift
for e in $*
do
expr $e - $n
n=$e
done|sort -n|while read e
do
n="$n + $e"
expr $n
done
```

Answer (score 0):

### Clojure, 46 bytes

```
#(reductions +(first %)(sort(map -(rest %)%)))
```

One day I'm going to make Cljr language which has shorter function names than Clojure.