# X Steps Forward, 1 Step Back

Tags: code-golf, number, sequence, integer

Here the first 100 numbers of an easy sequence:

```
0,1,0,2,1,4,3,7,6,11,10,16,15,22,21,29,28,37,36,46,45,56,55,67,66,79,78,92,91,106,105,121,120,137,136,154,153,172,171,191,190,211,210,232,231,254,253,277,276,301,300,326,325,352,351,379,378,407,406,436,435,466,465,497,496,529,528,562,561,596,595,631,630,667,666,704,703,742,741,781,780,821,820,862,861,904,903,947,946,991,990,1036,1035,1082,1081,1129,1128,1177,1176,1226
```

**How does this sequence work?**

```
n: 0 1     2           3     4     5     6     7     8      9       10      11      12

   0,      1-1=0,      2-1=1,      4-1=3,      7-1=6,       11-1=10,        16-1=15,      
     0+1=1,      0+2=2,      1+3=4,      3+4=7,      6+5=11,        10+6=16,        15+7=22
```

- `a(0) = 0`
- For every odd `n` (0-indexed), it's `a(n-1) + X` (where `X=1` and increases by 1 every time it's accessed)
- For every even `n` (0-indexed), it's `a(n-1) - 1`

### Challenge:

One of:

- Given an input integer `n`, output the `n`'th number in the sequence.
- Given an input integer `n`, output the first `n` numbers of the sequence.
- Output the sequence indefinitely without taking an input ([or taking an empty unused input](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12681/are-we-allowed-to-use-empty-input-we-wont-use-when-no-input-is-asked-regarding)).

### Challenge rules:

- Input `n` can be both 0- or 1-indexed.
- If you output (part of) the sequence, you can use a list/array, print to STDOUT with any delimiter (space, comma, newline, etc.). Your call.
- Please state which of the three options you've used in your answer.
- You'll have to support at least the first 10,000 numbers (10,000th number is `12,497,501`).

### General rules:

- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer in bytes wins.
  Don't let code-golf languages discourage you from posting answers with non-codegolfing languages. Try to come up with an as short as possible answer for 'any' programming language.
- [Standard rules apply](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet/2422#2422) for your answer, so you are allowed to use STDIN/STDOUT, functions/method with the proper parameters and return-type, full programs. Your call.
- [Default Loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.
- If possible, please add a link with a test for your code.
- Also, please add an explanation if possible.

### Test cases:

[Pastebin with the first 10,001 numbers in the sequence.](https://pastebin.com/JX6g4Nky) Feel free to pick any you'd like.

Some higher numbers:

```
n (0-indexed)    Output:

68,690           589,772,340
100,000          1,249,975,000
162,207          3,288,888,857
453,271          25,681,824,931
888,888          98,765,012,346
1,000,000        124,999,750,000
```

Answer (score 13):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>32</s> <s>28</s> 25 bytes

```python
lambda n:(~-n|1)**2/8+n%2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Xc5BCsIwEIXhvacIiNBUxJlJk5kI3sRNRYqCxiLdCOLVY2wxDb5VCF/C3z@H8z1Q7PaHeG1vx1Orwq56b8ILdV3TVtZhRbF/XMKgusqAXvzOTpwHvVTzrHhmMg1kg/BdiZAa79mm2xk5IuASGZJxljNqrCHGEpF1gpK@M5jV9KxUXthZwFTl/qrKrLFqyoL4AQ)

Returns the `n`-th number (`0`-indexed)

Answer (score 9):

## Excel, 31 bytes

Answer is `0` indexed.  Outputs the `n`the number.

```
=(A1^2+IF(ISODD(A1),7,-2*A1))/8
```

The sequence described is ultimately just two sequences interlaced:

```
ODD:   (x^2+x+2)/2
EVEN:  (x^2-x)/2
```

Interlacing these into one `0` indexed sequence gives:

```
a = (x^2 - 2x)/8 if even
a = (x^2 + 7 )/8 if odd
```

Which gives:

```
=IF(ISODD(A1),(A1^2+7)/8,(A1^2-2*A1)/8)
```

which we golf down to the `31` bytes.

---

Using the same approach, `1` indexed gives `37` bytes:

```
=(A1^2-IF(ISODD(A1),4*A1-3,2*A1-8))/8
```

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
Rj-ḣ⁸S
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z8oS/fhjsWPGncE////39AADAA)

0-indexed. Returns `n`th number.

Explanation:

```
Rj-ḣ⁸S Arguments: z
R      [1..x]: z (implicit)
 j-    Join x with y: ^, -1
   ḣ⁸  Take first y of x: ^, z
     S Sum: ^
```

Answer (score 5):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 23 bytes

```javascript
x=>(7+(x-2|1)**2)/8-x%2
```

1-indexed. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bcxBDoIwEEDRvafoxqTFVGamQFsT3HkQUorREEqEmC68e43sALc/L//ZvJvJvR7jLIfQ@tTVKdZXrk88SvqgyDISuZHxSMmFYQq9P/fhzjuuUIjDOllNJARjLM/ZLY7ezb69MESDRAo3GAEAf3qNqbC6BNjgylR2j0tjtSZVwJ/18t6tlzekLw)

```javascript
f(x) = f(x+1) + 1 if x is even
     = SUM{1..(x-3)/2} if x is odd

SUM{1..(x-3)/2}
= (1+(x-3)/2)*((x-3)/2)/2
= (x-1)*(x-3)/8
= ((x-2)^2-1)/8
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>40 38</s> 37 bytes

```hs
scanl(flip($))0$[1..]>>=(:[pred]).(+)
```

Returns an infinite list, [try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcpBCoAgEADAr3josBJJXYP6QS8wicW0pE0W7f1tzXlOrFcgElSTWqV6zASREkOjdd/YwRg3zxOMlkvYnTbQarkx5b/fyMumuKT8KJTXR8KjSueZPw)

#### Explanation

`scanl` takes three arguments `f`, `init` and `xs` (**[** *x<sub>0</sub>*, *x<sub>1</sub>* ... **]**) and builds a new list:

**[** *a<sub>0</sub> = init*, *a<sub>1</sub> = f(a<sub>0</sub>,x<sub>0</sub>)*, *a<sub>2</sub> = f(a<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>1</sub>)* ... **]**

We set `init = 0` and use the flipped `($)` application operator (thus it applies *a<sub>i</sub>* to the function *x<sub>i</sub>*), now we only need a list of functions - the list `[1..]>>=(:[pred]).(+)` is an infinite list with the right functions:

```hs
[(+1),(-1),(+2),(-1),(+3),(-1),(+4),...
```

#### Interesting alternative, 37 bytes

`flip` having the type `(a -> b -> c) -> b -> a -> c` we could also use `id :: d -> d` instead of `($)` because of Haskell's type inference the type `d` would be unified with `a -> b`, giving us the same.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyfmfqGCrEPO/ODkxL0cjLSezQCEzRdNAJdpQTy/Wzs5Wwyq6oCg1JVZTT0Nb839uYmYeUHluYoFvvEJBUWZeiULi/3/JaTmJ6cX/dZMLCgA)

**Edit**

<sup>-2 bytes by using `(>>=)` instead of `do`-notation.</sup>

<sup>-1 byte by using `scanl` instead of `zipWith`.</sup>

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
HḶS‘_Ḃ
```

A monadic link accepting (1-indexed) `n` which returns `a(n)`.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/j4Y5twY8aZsQ/3NH0//9/QyMA)** Or see the [test-suite](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/j4Y5twY8aZsQ/3NH0/@iew@2Pmta4//8fbWZhZmmoY2gABEDKzMjIwELHxNTYyNxIxwIELCFyBoax2jmZxSUaRYl56akaIB2GmpoA)

#### How?

```
HḶS‘_Ḃ - link: n
H      - halve         -> n/2.0
 Ḷ     - lowered range -> [0,1,2,...,floor(n/2.0)-1]
  S    - sum           -> TriangleNumber(floor(n/2.0)-1)
   ‘   - increment     -> TriangleNumber(floor(n/2.0)-1)+1
     Ḃ - bit = 1 if n is odd, 0 if it's even
    _  - subtract      -> TriangleNumber(floor(n/2.0)-1)+isEven(n)
```

Comment: Hm, interesting approach right there.

Answer (score 5):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 25 bytes

```hs
scanl(+)0$(:[-1])=<<[1..]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyfmfYxvzvzg5MS9HQ1vTQEXDKlrXMFbT1sYm2lBPL/Z/bmJmnoKtQkFRZl6JQs7/f8lpOYnpxf91kwsKAA)

Constructs an infinite list.

---

**[Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 27 bytes**

```hs
0:0%1
a%d=a+1:a:(a+d)%(d+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyfmfYxvz38DKQNWQK1E1xTZR29Aq0UojUTtFU1UjRdtQ839uYmaegq1CQVFmXolCzv9/yWk5ienF/3WTCwoA)

**[Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 30 bytes**

```hs
0:do a<-scanl(+)0[1..];[a+1,a]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyfmfYxvz38AqJV8h0Ua3ODkxL0dDW9Mg2lBPL9Y6OlHbUCcx9n9uYmaegq1CQVFmXolCzv9/yWk5ienF/3WTCwoA)

Answer (score 4):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>16</s> 12 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

Anonymous tacit prefix function. 0-indexed.

```apl
+/⊢↑∘∊¯1,¨⍨⍳
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Vc6xasMwEAbgvU/hvReqO1nSac6STAlxXsBQ3MXQrp0LIRhskiGQJUumbBn8Bn6UexH3FEipf05a9In7y6969v5d1p8fo3Sn9Vp2Bwzj65s0V9kdZX@WfTPcEYabtDr9WKmQtlO8XEnzM9xtct2p2Mz13i6WxVgl3CO9VJlnH032jLSXLHMcIQQCmxsFaFImAIHyCDE40JdEPJEJE2KBmIHTcUFJ7iwFnBBy4BmBKYdoUQ0/MjGRIXhdg6mN/2tj/hlM/6M2dibV@QU)

`+/` the sum of

`⊢↑` the first `n` elements

`∘∊` of the **ϵ**nlisted (flattened)

`¯1,¨⍨` negative-one-appended-to-each

`⍳` first `n` **ɩ**ndices (0 through `n`–1

Comment: Ah, that was my solution...guess it was similar enough.

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 10 bytes

```
ÎF<NÈi¼¾>+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//cJ@bjd/hjsxDew7ts9P@/9/MwszSAAA)

**Explanation**

```
Î             # initialize stack with: 0, input
 F            # for N in [0 ... input-1] do:
  <           # decrement the current number
   NÈi        # if N is even
      ¼       # increment a counter
       ¾>     # push counter+1
         +    # add to current number
```

Another 10-byter: `ÎFNÈN;Ì*<O`

Comment: `ÎGDN+D<` generates the sequence, but grabbing the nth element seems... hard in 3 bytes.

Answer (score 4):

## [PHP](http://php.net/), <s>73</s> <s>64</s> <s>55</s> <s>51</s> 47 bytes

## First method

First code golf answer!
I'm sure there's PHP tricks to make it shorter and the maths can probably be improved.

Takes n as the first argument and outputs the nth number in the sequence.

```
$y=$argv[1]/2;for(;$i<$y+1;)$x+=$i++;echo$x-($y|0);
```

Minus 9 bytes by removing "$x=0;" and "$i=0".

Minus 9 bytes thanks to @Kevin Cruijssen improving the for loop and loss of the end tag.

Minus 1 byte using bitwise or "|" rather than "(int)"

Minus 3 bytes thanks to @Dennis as you can remove the tags by running it from the command line with "php -r 'code here'"

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcRJCoAwDADAz@SgFHG5SSw@wQeIiLi1lybUIi34dqNzGDYsXc//kDQs/rzHeiobPMhnCLaDpGrMISoNVincV0MQiwzSU@UoIu3vJQ6W3CXFdhnyYSbe3RyWUw/uAw)

## Second method

Matched my previous answer with a whole new method!

```
for(;$i<$argv[1];$i++)$x+=($y^=1)?$i/2+1:-1;echo$x;
```

Using XOR and the tenary operator to switch between sums in the loop.

Edit: This doesn't work for n=0 and I have no idea why. $i isn't assigned so therefore it should be 0, therefore the loop `($i<$argv[1])` should fail as `(0<0==false)`, therefore a non assigned $x should output as 0 and not 1.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcZBCoAgEEDRy8zCkAjblUlH6ABREWXpxhlMoi7f5F88PjnirqfsgVFo8B2s8bxHNeWXsoBHGgHvbFTRg69qqdpSabs5hEczc5P7kJLHcHG5Xw5jWpBsWNJ6miH8)

## Third method

Converting the excel formula @Wernisch created to PHP gives a 47 byte solution

```
$z=$argv[1];echo(pow($z,2)+(($z&1)?7:-2*$z))/8;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAkVapsVRKL0suiDWOtU5Mz8jUK8ss1VKp0jDS1NYC0mqGmvbmVrpGWSpWmpr6F9f///y2B4F9@QUlmfl7xf92U4oz8opL4/ILUvPiSxHRb/zwA)

Comment: Hi, welcome to PPCG! If you haven't yet, [tips for golfing in PHP](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2913/tips-for-golfing-in-php) and [tips for golfing in <all languages>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5285/tips-for-golfing-in-all-languages) might be interesting to read through. Some things to golf: you can remove the trailing `?>`. Removing `$x=0` and `$i=0` is indeed allowed (if not, `$x=$i=0` would have been shorter as well). Also, the loop can be shortened to `for(;$i<$y+1;)$x+=$i++;`. Which is -15 bytes in total. Enjoy your stay! :)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen thanks very much!

Comment: You're welcome. Btw, your TIO is currently still 60 bytes instead of 58. And not sure why you've stated 57. [Try it online.](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxr4go4BLpdJWJbEovSzaMFbfyDotv0jDWiXTRqVS29BaU6VC21YlU1vbOjU5I1@lQlcjM69EU6XS@v///5ZAAAA)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I kept posting the wrong TIO! TIO says 58 now but I've posted 55 as you can remove "php" from the opening tag, just not in TIO

Comment: @Wernisch thanks for your formula!

Answer (score 4):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 32 bytes

```matlab
@(x)fix((x-~(m=mod(x,2)))^2/8)+m
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Zc1LCsIwFIXheVeRiZCLWnNv2zyEghO3IZS2kYIxIkUycusxbXFgPeOf7/h2bF59tHWe5/HEA9ghcB72b@5q5zsedgQAFzpo2Lpo/dM1I7v5@zWzXGppBLBpG3YOj74d@@7IKm2UoqIUKTGKaCl@EkSNRAWmAkXaP4JUGlWJydDzYF0YrWQlMB3JL7NAa2Z2RBY/)

Outputs the n-th number, 0-indexed. Uses the same formula as several other answers.

Answer (score 4):

## [Java (JDK 10)](http://jdk.java.net/), 20 bytes

```java
x->x%2+(x=~-x|1)*x/8
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY29jsIwEIT7PMU2JzlEMT/VSSFIlBSIAlGdKPYCQRsc27I3yBEHrx4cTlddsfq0M6OZBm@YN6frQK01jqGJv@yYlJwUyT@t7nTFZPRoVgq9hy2ShnsCYLtvRRV4Ro64GTpBGz2xZ0f68nUEdBefvqMAG80Hja7f2bNDNg7qcgj5KnwsMhHKZx5@5ukkTD@H4h2vjROkGQhKmBURS1iMzLK/QoB97/ncStOxtHGRlRa1RGtVv/ZxTlCa/pY9kvEewws)

Port of [TFeld's Python 2 anwser](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/165792/16236), so go give them an upvote! ;)

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>35</s> 34 bytes

```r
(u=(n=scan())-n%%2-1)-n+(15+u^2)/8
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/X6PUViPPtjg5MU9DU1M3T1XVSNcQSGtrGJpql8YZaepb/Dc0@Q8A)

First output option.Same formula as many other answers (I'd like to point to the first answer providing the formula, I can't figure which it is).

Second and third output options below:

#### [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 43 bytes

```r
function(m,n=1:m,u=n%%2+1)((n-u)^2-1)/8+2-u
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP08jVyfP1tAqV6fUNk9V1UjbUFNDI0@3VDPOSNdQU99C20i39H@ahpGh5n8A)

#### [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 51 bytes

```r
while(T){cat(((T-(u=T%%2+1))^2-1)/8+2-u," ");T=T+1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/vzwjMydVI0SzOjmxRENDI0RXo9Q2RFXVSNtQUzPOSNdQU99C20i3VEdJQUnTOsQ2RNuw9r@R4X8A)

Answer (score 4):

## Matlab/Octave, <s>31</s> 26 bytes

5 bytes saved thx to Luis Mendo!

```
@(n)sum(1:n/2+.5)-fix(n/2)
```

Comment: You can probably use `fix` instead of `floor`, and `n/2+.5` instead of `ceil(n/2)`

Comment: @LuisMendo Ty! Didn't know about `fix()` and didn't expect `1:n/2+.5` to work - so many things that could go wrong, but they actually don't :)

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 35 bytes

```r
diffinv(rbind(n<-1:scan(),-1)[n-1])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/PyUzLS0zr0yjKCkzL0Ujz0bX0Ko4OTFPQ1NH11AzOk/XMFbzv6HBfwA)

I thought this was an interesting alternative to [@JayCe's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/165853/67312) since it doesn't port very well to languages without built-in support for matrices, and happens to be just as golfy.

1-indexed, returns the first `n` elements of the sequence.

#### How it works:

`rbind(n<-1:scan(),-1)` constructs the following matrix:

```r
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    2    3    4
[2,]   -1   -1   -1   -1
```

Because R holds matrices in column-major order, if we were to convert this to a `vector`, we would obtain a vector

```r
1 -1 2 -1 3 -1 4 -1
```

which if we take a cumulative sum of, we would get

```r
1 0 2 1 4 3 7 6
```

which is the sequence, just without the leading `0`. `diffinv` fortunately adds the leading zero, so we take the first `n-1` values from the matrix and `diffinv` them, obtaining the first `n` values of the sequence.

Comment: I am a big fan of your 'diffinv' answers.

Comment: @JayCe credit to [user2390246 for introducing `diffinv` to me!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/138602/67312)

Answer (score 4):

## [Dodos](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/dodos), 69 bytes

```
	. w
w
	. h
	+ r . ' dab h '
h
	h ' '
	. dab
r
	
	r dip
.
	dot
'
	dip
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY69DsIwDITn@CluKAoI9YeO0Ik3aeNUyRKXNKhC4t2LpYrFd/5Osm8a17AvOaYywz4/xTt5p3KHJTcWDAOsl9nii@BHRu3qm/riPZywV7s5hbtpsNFGKoHMFRkNLHicEPSQIhU1GiujTIZMBseFGjIshTTSbddPRLNkRMSE6rz6Fzr03eUBFgL@NU89QxuiigpbWUrLwrIe8yimEUvy@w8)

---

Somehow this is the longest answer.

Explanation.

```
┌────┬─────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│Name│Function                                         │
├────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│.   │Alias for "dot", computes the sum.               │
├────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│'   │Alias for "dip".                                 │
├────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│r   │Range from 0 to n, reversed.                     │
├────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│h   │Halve - return (n mod 2) followed by (n/2) zeros.│
└────┴─────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Answer (score 4):

## [QBasic 1.1](http://www.qbasic.net/), 49 bytes

```
INPUT N
R=1
FOR I=1TO N\2-1
R=R+I
NEXT
?R-N MOD 2
```

1-indexed.

Answer (score 3):

## [QBasic 1.1](http://www.qbasic.net/), 30 bytes

```
INPUT N
?(N-1OR 1)^2\8+N MOD 2
```

Uses TFeld's algorithm. 0-indexed.

Answer (score 3):

## QBasic, 31 bytes

The just-implement-the-spec solution comes in slightly longer than [Erik's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166168/16766).

```
DO
?n
i=i+1
n=n+i
?n
n=n-1
LOOP
```

This outputs indefinitely. For purposes of running it, I recommend changing the last line to something like `LOOP WHILE INPUT$(1) <> "q"`, which will wait for a keypress after every second sequence entry and exit if the key pressed is `q`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-x`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 6 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Outputs the `n`th term, 1-indexed.

```
z oªUv
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LXg&code=eiBvqlV2&input=MTAw)

```
z oªUv     :Implicit input of integer U
z          :Floor divide by 2
  o        :Range [0,Uz)
   ª       :Logical OR of each with
    Uv     :Parity of U
           :Implicit output of sum
```

Answer (score 2):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 56 bytes

```cs
n=>{int a=0,i=0;for(;++i<n;)a+=i%2<1?-1:i/2+1;return a;}
```

*-2 bytes thanks to Kevin Crujssen*

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVNNa9tAED1bv2IwLUhonO6uviMrpRRySqG0hx5CDoq8ThaUVZDkNkXot7tvbceEUPDsx@zMvPc042ZYNV2v901bDwN977uHvn6iyRvGejQN/fw7jPrp4npnm7WxI8OuaEsV7W11NeFGdSXYVKLcdr1fhqFZ2zKow8p8VGv5eSUvzScVyrLX4663VJfzvvS85919i@InjN@d2dC32lg/mLwFat7eETj1uhl/6GHXjgPwrP5DhydvMQmWLFhhjTnijFOWkiW8OCSsFCvJqmCVc5RxlHKMX8JJyknCKcJTzgrOci4UFy4RaSJhiSypUAVJMnKlYljEMgNShjcXWwAXYApoKgJQhDPiFOJUlsFSjoSECY4UzirhKFEw@AAaATUWGQyUHLMoATvHEHsBfwGSoJ6Ae5IqmOTE@QowB1YaCdB3EqBBxDDojxVMQpAzwTl05NCRIz9HfoG4AnFFnMFSLqCjgA4pnEgBBlLkyi3QJwGOJccCOVgQotRhSWZ0buHa7Npu0BNRYlu/69XFjbYP4yOewjDAIC0WX4ZB96NvQsnvYm/NXVB6i9mb/zsTr4mAs@y6T/rlGdl6A/CVDDw3Llvyz941iQDzAcw3gQIIbqroBRfpLtBAZxHyKMIeCePVpR/KYoSpQv5RxZuaq1MdEHfudtBufxcUVvQShuew2ck8TDfVzbirW0BvfRu4b3rfdS31h08C7@tzdVbrYk5/xK@dHbpWX/zqzahvjNX@h@U15Bj7vBtpsvMlTa9pM9V2Q9Ox3kxLCsk/oXym5VM9No9LuqTlpiPbjXR0BGCEfuwfddt2/wA)

1 indexed. Returns `a(n)`

Ungolf'd:

```cs
int f(int n)
{
    // a needs to be outside the for loop's scope,
    // and it's golfier to also define i here
    int a = 0, i = 1;
    // basic for loop, no initializer because we already defined i
    for (; ++i < n;)
    {
        if (i%2 < 1) {
            // if i is even, subtract 1
            a -= 1;
        }
        else
        {
            // if i is odd, add (i / 2) + 1
            // this lets us handle X without defining another int
            a += i / 2 + 1;
        }
    }
    // a is the number at index n
    return a;
}
```

Comment: `i=1;for(;i<n;i++)` can be `i=0;for(;++i<n;)` and `i%2==0` can be `i%2<1`.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen so I can, thanks! I should've seen the 2nd one, but I didn't thnk the first one would work as I thought for loops only checked the conditional after the first loop. TIL

Comment: Nope, it checks before the first iteration already. A `do-while` will check after completing the first iteration. :)

Comment: In very rare cases you could even merge an `if` with a `for`-loop. For example: `if(t>0)for(i=0;i<l;i++)` to `for(i=0;t>0&i<l;i++)`. I've almost never been able to use this in my answers, though.

Comment: that's pretty awesome, I'll definitely have to keep that in mind next time I do C# golfing, which is quite rare these days :P most of my C# work is decidedly ungolfy

Comment: You can remove `i` and use `n` directly instead, saving 4 bytes: `n=>{int a=0;for(;n-->1;)a+=n%2<1?-1:n/2+1;return a;}`

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>11</s> <s>9</s> 8 bytes

```
ΘṁṠe→Θ∫N
```

Saved a byte thanks to H.PWiz.
Outputs as an infinite list.
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ARoA5f9odXNr///OmOG5geG5oGXihpLOmOKIq07//w)

#### Explanation

```
ΘṁṠe→Θ∫N
      ∫N   Cumulative sum of natural numbers (triangular numbers).
     Θ     Prepend 0.
 ṁṠe→      Concatenate [n + 1, n] for each.
Θ          Prepend 0.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

Return the first `n` numbers.

```
Rj-ÄŻḣ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z8oS/dwy9HdD3cs/v//v6EBAA)

Comment: Very similar to EriktheOutgolfer's answer.

Answer (score 2):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 23 bytes

```
00v
1->:n9o{1+{{:{+:n9o
```

I've never done any ><> golfing before, so this can almost certainly be shorter! Is there any way to initialize the stack with two zeros on it?

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/38CgjMtQ184qzzK/2lC7utqqWhvE/v8fAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/Flakheads/BrainHack), <s>68</s> 42 bytes

```
{({}[()]<({}([{}]()))>)}{}({({}[()])}{}{})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzLSEzO/v@/WqO6NlpDM9YGSGtEV9fGamhqatpp1gJ5MCkQp7pW8////xYA)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, <s>49</s> <s>48</s> 45 bytes

```javascript
x=>eval('for(i=0,r=1;++i<x+2;)r+=i%2?-1:i/2')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dcxLDsIgFEDRufswhWAtPJXWVnQtpIJ5iqUB09TV42dmiHd4BveqJx37gOOjjCOeTbj74Waeyao0q6OZtCOF9YGg4qugRMcYHmYGHQ1M4RJOpWixgoKm3g/RO7N2/kIskY3cc0oXvyr4p5wlAK8z3u42UIuMm29/3u95egE)

Not as pretty as @tsh answer, but mine works for bigger numbers.

And now thanks @tsh, for the `eval` solution !

Comment: `<=x+1` can be `<x+2`

Comment: `x=>eval('for(i=0,r=1;++i<x+2;)r+=i%2?-1:i/2')` should be shorter.

Comment: Does `eval` return the last modified value ? I still don't fully understand what it can do.

Comment: It return the value of statement (which _may_ be covered in `do` statement in later version).

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 15 bytes

```
Ｉ∨ΣＥＮ⎇﹪ι²±¹⊕⊘ι⁰
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DYhBCgIxDEWv0mUGKqg7cenGWcwo6AViJ2ihTYeYDnj6mLf47/PSByU1LGZ3yaxwwa/CTeDRK0y4wshr17nXFwkMMTxJGOUHU1t6aZBjOHqd6Y1KcPA7chKqxEoLXLFsrjw4Mex9z2Ynx3Zb@QM) 0-indexed. Link is to verbose version of code. The formula would probably be shorter, but what's the fun in that? Explanation:

```
    Ｎ           Input as a number
   Ｅ            Map over implicit range
     ⎇          Ternary
      ﹪ι²       Current value modulo 2
         ±¹     If true (odd) then -1
           ⊕⊘ι  Otherwise calculate X as i/2+1
  Σ             Take the sum
 ∨            ⁰ If the sum is empty then use zero
Ｉ               Cast to string and implicitly print
```

Answer (score 1):

## Befunge 93, 26 bytes

```
<v0p030
 >:.130g+:30p+:.1-
```

Runs indefinitely
[Try it online](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT/3/36bMoMDA2IBLwc5Kz9DYIF3bytigQBvI1v3/HwA), though output gets a little wonky and goes back down after x=256, presumably TIO can't handle characters above U+256. Works fine at https://www.bedroomlan.org/tools/befunge-playground (Chrome only, unfortunately. With Firefox, endlines get removed at runtime, for some reason...)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 8 bytes

```
s<s,R_1S
```

Returns `n`th number in the sequence, 0-indexed. [Try it online](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=s%3Cs%2CR_1S&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=0%0A1%0A2%0A3%0A4%0A5%0A6%0A7%0A8%0A9%0A9999&debug=0)

Explanation, with example for `n=5`:

```
s<s,R_1SQQ   Final 2 Q's are implicit, Q=eval(input())

       SQ    1-indexed range        [1,2,3,4,5]
   ,R_1      Map each to [n,-1]     [[1,-1],[2,-1],[3,-1],[4,-1],[5,-1]]
  s          Sum (Flatten)          [1,-1,2,-1,3,-1,4,-1,5,-1]
 <       Q   Take 1st Q             [1,-1,2,-1,3]
s            Sum, implicit output   4
```

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 17 bytes

```
1#.[{._1,@,.~1+i.
```

A port of Adám's APL solution.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Vc9NCgIxDAXg/Zwi6GIQQ2jSv3RAEA/gBVy4EAd142KWolevrTJiH3SVj@bllsdpQ2BgAJN5SYcHHRm3SC9eXymvugVBP26oB4TnAOPUdefT5Q4jBA3JQMl@R/CN14QxClpnZsWmplGM4hKm6LFMfi6ImNg4i6KKWp@Ps3PeSuTGicegjCoOk@UZ6icNTIoxlK1cG4a2ofmDXH9K5RRvasX8Bg)

Answer (score 1):

## [Convex](https://github.com/GamrCorps/Convex), <s>10</s> 9 bytes

```
_½,ª)\2%-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S87PK0ut@P8//tBenUOrNGOMVHX///9vaAAChgA)

Based on Jonathan Allan's Jelly approach (which was probably based on OP editing the question with another definition of the sequence). 1-indexed.

Explanation:

```
_½,ª)\2%- Stack: [A]
_         Duplicate. Stack: [A A]
 ½        Halve. Stack: [A [A]½]
  ,       Range, [0..⌊N⌋). Stack: [A [[A]½],]
   ª      Sum. Stack: [A [[A]½],]ª]
    )     Increment. Stack: [A [[[A]½],]ª])]
     \    Swap. Stack: [[[[A]½],]ª]) A]
      2   2. Stack: [[[[A]½],]ª]) A 2]
       %  Modulo. Stack: [[[[A]½],]ª]) [A 2]%]
        - Minus. Stack: [[[[[A]½],]ª]) [A 2]%]-]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org),  <s>38</s>  26 bytes

```perl6
{(0,{$_+(($+^=1)??++$ !!-1)}...*)[$_]}
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/##VZBBT9wwEIXv@RUPEYjDBitZIKRabemhlXriygFBZJIBTB072E7parW/fbEDqsTBmif7m@c3M5JV9X5yhL8171ZJMmxw3JmesN5vWVls03bBWLq4X1f51dVikeLg4LTKd5zzk/w2be92eyc2iB2s5Lwqy5y/GKlZVmR5sBsnz2J10wOE2@jutJduVKGFpW2ObQIcQnp0QsOLPwQBZfQTvBwI3uCJNFnhg34mOHqdSHc0NzmDN4KddPDFIPQm1tE4Jx8UQWqMwgqlSCUBHyf3DOej0Y/RmkE6ckW8sB4xP38cPMuOmj7LC2RYf0dWgM@L@Hyqzvt5oPj1EIO6yX6kCn4dOYfekNOZB/0L80zaSxWfQ6zAhSCBk9pTHxx@Xf@EeBMB@x9mleyShB9/XdGjsWCBB@qmrb@VRdRhxW1Zfup62S7Ly1mfX5y1y8tq1k3TtOEEXUX2g89X@9@klMGNsap/Bw)

```perl6
{(+^-$_+|1)**2 div 8+$_%2}
```

Based on reverse engineering TFeld's [Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/165791/x-steps-forward-1-step-back/165792#165792).
[Try it](https://tio.run/##NY5BbsIwEEX3PsVfBGyT1LJdMK4QXfcG3dUCHCQqB0cJQUKUs6d2ShejedL8/zRt3QUzDn2NqxGHDSHNDfND9DW2452VXy@FK38UXyw0/OkKWxZuph9jv7uBSSGUlFw0u5ZNHS6@4@nMaEV5MrXDheXdD/vU7duQO4XjuBMgC8SxuTA6s57yChTbd9AKYjI9T2rps@pBiJj/K46xA0sGwFhn3mSVOf3hpHyy0U7L9cTL1avTazWxtdalSaxy9i/PN@NHHULEZ@yC/wU)

### Expanded

#### 38 byte (sequence generator):

```perl6
{  # bare block lambda with implicit parameter $_

  (
    # generate a new sequence everytime this function is called

    0,    # seed the sequence

    {     # bare block that is used to generate the rest of the values

      $_  # parameter to this inner block (previous value)

      +

      (
          # a statement that switches between (0,1) each time it is run
          ( $ +^= 1 )

        ??     # when it is 1 (truish)
          # a statement that increments each time it is run
          ++$ # &prefix:« ++ »( state $foo )

        !!     # or else subtract 1
          -1
      )
    }

    ...  # keep generating until:

    *    # never stop

  )[ $_ ] # index into the sequence
}
```

Note that this has the benefit that you can pass in `*` to get the entire sequence, or pass in a Range to more efficiently generate multiple values.

#### 26 byte (direct calculation):

```perl6
{  # bare block lambda with implicit parameter $_

  (

    +^     # numeric binary negate
      -$_  # negative of the input
      +|   # numeric binary or
      1

  ) ** 2   # to the power of 2

  div 8     # integer divide it by 8

  + $_ % 2  # add one if it is odd
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 8 bytes

```
;L¨O>¹É-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/f2ufQCn@7QzsPd@r@/29oAAKGAA)

Based on Jonathan Allan's Jelly approach (which was probably based on OP editing the question with another definition of the sequence), so 1-indexed.

Comment: +1. I had a similar approach prepared in 05AB1E which I planned to post in a few days if no-one else posted one. It's slightly different (I first decrease the halve before creating the list, instead of removing the tail; and I use `I` instead of `¹`), but the general approach and byte-count is exactly the same: [`;<LO>IÉ-`](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/f2sbH387zcKfu//@GBiBgCAA)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Would've posted yesterday if I had the ability to think more deeply, but, well, this is finals period, thinking too deeply about this is forbidden. :P

Comment: Ah, I'm glad I don't have finals anymore. I am pretty busy at work as well though, and have to postpone code-golf sometimes more often than I would like. ;p Good luck with your exams!

Answer (score 1):

## [Oasis](https://github.com/Adriandmen/Oasis), 7 bytes

```
>vLSnv-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08sziz@/9@uzCc4r0z3////lgA)

---

**Sequential solution**

## [Oasis](https://github.com/Adriandmen/Oasis), 12 bytes

```
bn>v>n2%*<+0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08sziz@/z8pz67MLs9IVctG2@D///@GBgYGhgA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
é╛▼¥,▐_
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=82be1f9d2cde5f&i=0%0A1%0A2%0A3%0A4%0A5%0A6%0A7%0A8%0A9%0A10%0A68690%0A100000%0A162207%0A453271%0A888888%0A1000000&a=1&m=2)

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Classic)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 9 bytes

```apl
+\¯1⌈-\∘⍳
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob2pm/qO2CYb/04Ckdsyh9YaPejp0Yx51zHjUu/n//zQFQwMDAA)

uses ⎕io←1

Answer (score 1):

## GMS2, 39 bytes

```
a=argument0 return a*a/8+(a mod 2?7:a*-2)/8
```

With GMS1 it takes 43 bytes:

```
a=argument0 b=a*-2if a mod 2b=7return a*a/8+b/8
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Charm](https://github.com/Aearnus/charm), 64 bytes

```
1 setref [ 1 ] [ 0 getref + put 1 - put 0 [ 1 + ] modref ] while
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILMr9/99QoTi1pCg1TSFawVAhFkgaKKRDBLQVCkpLgIK6YNoArEAbqCQ3PwUkHatQnpGZk/r/PwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 21 bytes

A straight port of [TFeld's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/165792/78274) also works in Ruby:

```ruby
->n{(~-n|1)**2/8+n%2}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Vc7LCsIwEIXhvU9REEErxZlJ55KFvoh046LLIGoX4uXVY2yNxrMK4Uv4T8PhGvttbHbhtnw24Y6ruqaNrcOCHvE4XM5Vv3fQzT5HMfHQzavf2LwquRYyQXivNEit98rp9muECLQ0jmwcazYtO1IsDbEYWvrMYUbToxJ5U2HAVCT/RWXSWDQlQXwB)

Answer (score 1):

## [Common Lisp](http://www.clisp.org/), 75 bytes

```lisp
(defun f(n)(+(/((lambda(x)(*(- x 1)x))(+(floor n 2)(mod n 2)))2)(mod n 2)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYk5CoAwEEWvMuUfRVyKoMeJxoFANqJCbh@Xzu4tm7NHqhVmlyuQIDBa9IDTfjUahdGgo0IjF36XuBgzBZoYPpoPmH9SkbINJ4TUrJbhCTc)

Not the best.  I'm still learning Lisp.