# Tips for Golfing in ARM

Tags: code-golf, tips, machine-code

*Because [ARM is the July 2021 LoTM](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23648/language-of-the-month-for-july-2021-arm), I figured I'd create the tips thread.*

ARM is probably the most successful architecture for the digital world. From mobile phones to supercomputers, ARM is everywhere! Consequently, let's have a thread where we can help each other shorten our ARM code.

One tip per answer, and no stupid tips like "oh remove comments and whitespace".

Comment: Arm has comments and whitespace?

Comment: @user "oh remove comments and whitespace" is just an indicator of the types of tips that aren't exactly helpful

Comment: There is quite a bit of variation between the different versions (Aarch64, Jazelle, Cortex-m) so it may be helpful for each answer to specify the exact execution environment.

Comment: Finally, a chance to share my infinite wisdom.

Answer (score 3):

## Use `s` instructions to your advantage.

#### ARM

Unlike x86, ARM lets you choose whether to set the condition codes on its instructions, by suffixing the instructions with `s`. This is useful for do-while loops, where you can subtract, do some things, and keep that condition set until you want to branch or conditionally execute.

```c
loop:
        // Subtract from r0, set condition codes
        subs    r0, r0, #1
        // idk, do something silly
        ldr     r1, [r0, r2]
        add     r1, r3, r1, lsl #2
        str     r1, [r0, r2]
        // condition codes are still set from subs
        // loop while r0 is not zero
        bne     loop
```

### Thumb-2

This applies in a different way on Thumb-2.

In Thumb-2, most of the narrow instructions always set the condition codes*, while wide instructions give you the freedom of choice. However, the assembler won't warn you if it is using the wide instruction.

Take the following "Hello World" program:

```c
        .syntax unified
        .arch armv6t2
        .thumb
        .thumb_func
        .globl _start
_start:
        mov     r0, #1      // stdout
        adr     r1, .Lhello // "Hello, World!"
        mov     r2, #13     // string length
        mov     r7, #4      // sys_write
        svc     #0          // write(1, "Hello, World!", 13)
        mov     r7, #1      // sys_exit
        svc     #0          // exit(dontcare)
        // UNREACHABLE
.Lhello:
        .ascii "Hello, World!"
```

This is very inefficient, as `mov Rd, #imm` is a wide instruction:

```c
00000000 <_start>:
   0:   f04f 0001       mov.w   r0, #1
   4:   f20f 0110       addw    r1, pc, #16 // adr r1, .Lhello
   8:   f04f 020d       mov.w   r2, #13
   c:   f04f 0704       mov.w   r7, #4
  10:   df00            svc     #0
  12:   f04f 0701       mov.w   r7, #1
  16:   df00            svc     #0
```

Instead, if you use `movs` which sets the condition codes, you get a much smaller result:

```c
00000000 <_start>:
   0:   2001            movs    r0, #1
   2:   f20f 010c       addw    r1, pc, #12 // adr r1, .Lhello
   6:   220d            movs    r2, #13
   8:   2704            movs    r7, #4
   a:   df00            svc     0
   c:   2701            movs    r7, #1
   e:   df00            svc     0
```

<sup>Note: 2 bytes can be saved here by [placing this code at an address that is not 4 byte aligned](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/230923/94093)</sup>

*There is one exception. IT blocks.

IT Blocks will prevent condition codes from being set, even on narrow instructions (aside from ones like `cmp` and `tst` where it is pointless not to).

If you are in a situation where you want to chain up to 4 instructions together without setting the condition codes, you can use `it al`.

Note that this is only beneficial for two or more instructions, as IT blocks require an opcode themselves. For only one, it might just be better to use a wide instruction or to `cmp` again.

Answer (score 1):

## ARM/Thumb: Use block loads/stores

`ldm`, `stm`, `push`, and `pop` are pretty cool. They let you load/store multiple registers in order, optionally incrementing or decrementing before or after.

It can be useful for large literal pools instead of a chain of `ldr`s.

In Thumb-2, this also lets you postincrement without a wide instruction.

```c
    // *r1++ = r0
    str     r0, [r1], #4 // f841 0b04
    stm     r1!, {r0}    // c101
```

Answer (score 0):

## Thumb: Make sure your literal pools are aligned.

The PC-relative instructions `adr` and `ldr =x` will only be narrow instructions if they are accessing a 4 byte aligned pointer.

Simply reordering things or adding padding can make your literal pools aligned and prevent a wide instruction. This can often create a chain reaction when you have multiple constants, as the act of making one `ldr`/`adr` aligned will change the alignment of other literals, this can be for better or worse.

Another option is to load your code at an address that is **not** 4 byte aligned, so the literal **is** 4 byte aligned. You can typically just put a `nop` at the top of the code to simulate this (assemblers will align your code by default)